# Can't understand this if statement

Tags: c, if-statement

I've a C university exam coming up next week and i was looking at old exam papers a one of the questions gives this fragmented bit of code.

```
int a=2, b=-1, c=0;

   if (a-2||b&&c||a){

     printf("True\n");

   } else {

     printf("False\n");

   }
```

We have to determine what the output of this code will be but the if statement makes no sense to me any if statement I've come across has been very specific like saying

```
if( x == 0)
```

I don't know what this is looking for my only assumption is that its going to be always true. Am I right or is there more to it then that?

Comment: Note that your last example (`if (x = 0)`) is an assignment and the body of the if statement will never be executed.  Maybe you had `if (x == 0)` in mind.

Comment: Check the documentation of [`C` operators precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). It also links to the description pages of each type of `C` operators.

Comment: The if statement contains an expression and you need to evaluate it by taking operator precedence into account. If it evaluates to 0 it's wrong, otherwise it's true.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  You think that the `if` statement evaluates to true, but you've not explained why you think that.  The explanation is the key.  It's exam-worthy code only; you shouldn't see anything as bad outside an exam (but people continue to surprise me).  There are a few things you have to consider: (1) how C evaluates expressions for true/false; (2) how each term in the expression evaluates to true/false; and (3) how the `||` and `&&` operators interact.  At least this code has no side-effects in the expressions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This assignment has two goals:

- to show what booleans are in C: Essentially they evaluate to ints with false mapping to 0 and true mapping to 1. In turn, any numeric or pointer value can be used in an integer context, with the respective zero value (0, 0.0, NULL (pointer), 0.0f, 0L etc.) evaluating as false and all others as true.
- to show the precedence of operators

`&&` has a higher precedence than `||`, so this statement is equivalent to

```
a-2 || (b&&c) || a
```

which will evaluate to `true` if any of the values is true.

As `a==2`, `a-2` is 0. `c` is 0, so `b && c` is 0 as well.

So we have `0 || 0 || a`, which is true as `a` is 2.

Comment: `0.0` and `0.0f` also evaluate to false.

Comment: *Any* type that has the value zero evaluates to false, even a pointer.  Strictly though C99 introduced booleans as a specific type.

Comment: You are both right, but my intent was to show the opposite direction. But I edited my answer now to show both directions.

Answer (score 2):

Most languages interprets non-zero integers as **true** and zero as **false**, so here you would have to calculate each one of the terms. Without any parenthesis, I would suggest that [the && statement is taken in account first](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). So we have:

```
if (2-2 // gives zero
|| // OR
-1 && 0 // -1 AND 0 gives false
|| // OR
a) // Which is 2, which is true
```

So you're right, this statement is always **true**. This exercice was about showing predecence orders, and the fact that everything is numerical, even in boolean logic.
This is really important for you to understand.

If the predecence was the other way around (|| > &&), you must understand that it would have been **false** instead. I think this example's whole point is here.

```
(a-2 || b) && (c || a)
false && true
--> false
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that truth and falsity in C is always numerical.

https://www.le.ac.uk/users/rjm1/cotter/page_37.htm

Namely, anything that evaluates to numerical zero is false, and anything that evaluates to numerical non-zero is true.

Answer (score 1):

In **c** language integers 0 is treated as **false** and any non-zero integer value is **true** but it should be noted that it is language specific and the sme statement will show compilation error in java as java is more strict and integers are not converted to booleans.

Talking about the above assignment problem the expression inside if statement will evaluate to `true` as 
`(a-2||b&&c||a)` is same as 
`(2-2||-1&&0||2)` which is same as 
`(0||0||2)` which is evaluated as 
`(false||false||true)` and hence the entire expression evaluates to 
`true`.
*hope it helps*.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a=2, b=-1, c=0;

int first=a-2; //0 -> false
bool second= b&& c; // nonZero&&zero -> true&&false -> false
int third = 2; //  nonZero -> true

// false|| false|| true -> true
   if (first || second || third ){

     printf("True\n");

   } else {

     printf("False\n");

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to understand two things before solving this problem that is
operator precedence and 
associativity of operators

operator precedence tells c compiler that which operation to perform first.
and if two operators have same precedence than associativity tells evaluate left to right or right to left in you expression

```
int a=2, b=-1, c=0;

   if (a-2||b&&c||a){
```

you can think it as

```
    if((a-2)||(b&&c)||a){}
means - has top precedence so it will solved first
reduced to if(0||(b&&c)||a){}
then && has higher precedence so
reduced to if(0||false||a)
then the associativity is left to right so 
reduced to if(false||a)
that is(false||2)
return true
```

Answer (score -1):

In almost every programming language as far as I know 0 means false and 1 means true.

So coming up to your question: you have used `&&` and `||` operators. Both of these are called Logical operators.
Now first block of yours is `a-2||b  :-
2-2||-1` so `0||-1`. Now since the right expression of `||` is `-1` the or operator will return 1 i.e. True because one of the values of 0 and -1 is non-zero 0 i.e. -1.

Therefore the expression resolves to `1&&c||a`  :-

Now `c=0`, therefore `1&&0` returns a 0 because `&&` will only return 1 if both the expressions right and left of it are non zero.
So expression becomes `0||2`  :-

Now since `||` (or operator) requires only one of operands either on right or left side to be non zero hence 0||2 returns 1.

Now your `if (a-2||b&&c||a)` statement resolves to

```
if (1)
{

     printf("True\n");  }
else......
```

Therefore since 1 means TRUE the if statement will execute and you will get output as True.

Comment: You are wrong in your first sentence: in Java, e. g., you have to explicitly compare to 0 in order to get a boolean expression.

Comment: That's why bro i said almost every programming languages which include c,c++ and exclude java,etc and there's a big difference between almost every and every i hope u get my point.